# How do I retrieve the current user in wordpress through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, user-interface

I have the following code which works. (When I press the button "test" is displayed on the input form.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel- 
 core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<script>
function btn1() {
document.getElementsByName("admin-status")[0].value = "test";
}
</script>
```

I want to retrieve the username, so I thought I added it correctly, but it says not defined.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel- 
 core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<script>
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
function btn1() {
document.getElementsByName("admin-status")[0].value = $current_user;
}
</script>
```

What am I missing? Thanks. Noob here.

Answer (score 6):

The better way to add localize script

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp12311_enqueue_scripts' );

function wp12311_enqueue_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'wp12311-scripts', 'your_script_path/test.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
     wp_localize_script( 'wp12311-scripts', 'test', array(
         'current_user' => wp_get_current_user()
     ) ) );
}
```

Now in `test.js` file you can access current user data like

```
var displayName = test.current_user.display_name;
```

Comment: where should we add the add_action ?

Comment: In theme `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably see a " is undefined" in js console and/or other errors. Note that you forgot the php `<?php`  and `?>` around the php code, and the `$current_user` would be `"<?php echo $current_user ?>`

If you are doing anything more than one line script you really should [enqueue script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and then [localize script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to a variable you can use in js on the page anywhere, not mix php and js!